# Reshaping from wide to long format

Tags: bash, parsing, unix

I am trying to use unix to transform a tab delimited file from a short/wide format to long format, in a similar way as the reshape function in R.  I hope to create three rows for each row in the starting file.  Column 4 currently contains 3 values separated by commas.  I hope to keep columns 1, 2, and 3 the same for each starting row, but have column 4 be one of the values from the initial column 4.  This example probably makes it more clear than I can describe verbally:

```
current file:  
A1  A2  A3  A4,A5,A6  
B1  B2  B3  B4,B5,B6  
C1  C2  C3  C4,C5,C6  

goal:  
A1  A2  A3  A4  
A1  A2  A3  A5  
A1  A2  A3  A6  
B1  B2  B3  B4  
B1  B2  B3  B5  
B1  B2  B3  B6  
C1  C2  C3  C4  
C1  C2  C3  C5  
C1  C2  C3  C6
```

As someone just becoming familiar with this language, my initial thought was to use sed to find the commas replace with a hard return

`sed 's/,/&\n/' data.frame`

I am really not sure how to include the values for columns 1-3.  I had low hopes of this working, but the only thing I could think of was to try inserting the column values with {print $1, $2, $3}.

`sed 's/,/&\n{print $1, $2, $3}/' data.frame`

Not to my surprise, the output looked like this:

```
A1  A2  A3  A4  
{print $1, $2, $3}  A5  
{print $1, $2, $3}  A6  
B1  B2  B3  B4  
{print $1, $2, $3}  B5  
{print $1, $2, $3}  B6  
C1  C2  C3  C4  
{print $1, $2, $3}  C5  
{print $1, $2, $3}  C6
```

It seems like an approach might be to store the values of columns 1-3 and then insert them.  I am not really sure how to store the values, I think that it may involve using an adaptation of the following script, but I am having a hard time understanding all of the components.

`NR==FNR{a[$1, $2, $3]=1}`

Thanks in advance for your thoughts on this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can a write simple `read` loop for this and use brace expansion for parsing the comma delimited field:

```
#!/bin/bash

while read -r f1 f2 f3 c1; do
  # split the comma delimited field 'c1' into its constituents
  for c in ${c1//,/ }; do
     printf "$f1 $f2 $f3 $c\n"
  done
done < input.txt
```

Output:

```
A1 A2 A3 A4
A1 A2 A3 A5
A1 A2 A3 A6
B1 B2 B3 B4
B1 B2 B3 B5
B1 B2 B3 B6
C1 C2 C3 C4
C1 C2 C3 C5
C1 C2 C3 C6
```

Comment: Why use a subshell running sed? Wouldn't `${c1//,/ }` be sufficient?

Answer (score 1):

As solution without calling an external program :

```
#!/bin/bash

data_file="d"

while IFS=" " read -r f1 f2 f3 r
do
  IFS="," read f4 f5 f6 <<<"$r"
  printf "$f1 $f2 $f3 $f4\n$f1 $f2 $f3 $f5\n$f1 $f2 $f3 $f6\n"
done <"$data_file"
```

Answer (score 1):

In the great Miller there is the [nest verb](http://johnkerl.org/miller/doc/reference-verbs.html#nest) to do it

With

```
mlr --nidx --ifs "\t" nest --explode --values  --across-records -f 4 --nested-fs ","  input.tsv
```

you will have

```
A1 A2 A3 A4
A1 A2 A3 A5
A1 A2 A3 A6
B1 B2 B3 B4
B1 B2 B3 B5
B1 B2 B3 B6
C1 C2 C3 C4
C1 C2 C3 C5
C1 C2 C3 C6
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need the output to be in any particular order within a group of the fourth column, the following awk one-liner might do:

```
awk '{split($4,a,","); for(i in a) print $1,$2,$3,a[i]}' input.txt
```

This works by splitting your 4th column into an array, then for each element of the array, printing the "new" four columns.

If order is important -- that is, A4 must come before A5, etc, then you can use a classic `for` loop:

```
awk '{split($4,a,","); for(i=1;i<=length(a);i++) print $1,$2,$3,a[i]}' input.txt
```

But that's awk. And you're asking about bash.

The following might work:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

mapfile -t arr < input.txt

for s in "${arr[@]}"; do
  t=($s)
  mapfile -t -d, u <<<"${t[3]}"
  for v in "${u[@]}"; do
    printf '%s %s %s %s\n' "${t[@]:0:3}" "${v%$'\n'}"
  done
done
```

This copies your entire input file into the elements of an array, and then steps through that array, mapping each 4th-column into a second array. It then steps through that second array, printing the first three columns from the first array, along with the current field from the second array.

It's obviously similar in structure to the `awk` alternative, but much more cumbersome to read and code.

Note the `${v%$'\n'}` on the `printf` line. This strips off the last field's trailing newline, which doesn't get stripped by `mapfile` because we're using an alternate delimiter.

Note also that there's no reason you *have* to copy all your input into an array, I just did it that way to demonstrate a little more of `mapfile`.  You could of course use the old standard,

```
while read s; do
   ...
done < input.txt
```

if you prefer.

Comment: A few question about `mapfile`, as I have not used it before and am curious.  Usually, when reading a file, if you need to split it in lines, it means you are probably going to iterate over these lines and thus have a `while` loop anyway later on.  Maybe it performs better?  But then to really benefit from it, you would need a file big enough that loading it in memory might become an issue.  If you need to keep the inside of the loop in the scope of the main shell, you can use `<()` instead of a pipe.  Are there real-world scenarios where `mapfile` would seem like a natural fit?

Comment: @Fred, you're right to question performance. This stuff is always hard to evaluate. What it usually comes down to for me is that even if a performance difference is *detectable*, I won't consider it a factor unless it's *noticeable*. Sure, stuff can be measured. But all other things being equal, if it doesn't affect your day, then go with whatever feels right or is faster to program, because it really doesn't matter which method you pick.

Comment: I understand what you are saying.  My question was more trying to find out in which cases (in read life) you would tend to use `mapfile` instead of `read` with a loop or awk script.  I am trying to figure out when `mapfile` would be your "best engineering compromise".

Comment: @Fred, of course "all other things" are not equal most of the time. The OP hasn't mentioned how large his dataset is, but if it's many gigabytes, then an approach that loads data into memory might be impossible. In that case, awk or input redirection are the way to go, though the internal mapfile can still be useful.

Comment: @Fred, in terms of coming up with a use-case .. The use cases for mapfile are the same as the use cases for a read loop. It outperforms a read loop significantly, but it doesn't really do anything that couldn't also be done with a read loop, with the exception of the `-C` callback option.